# CSS - selector for first element anywhere under a parent

Tags: html, css

How can I get the selector for "Label 1" below without having to use specific divs? I thought `#wrapper label:first-of-type` would do the trick but that appears to be selecting every label.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="content-1">
            <label>Label 1</label>
        </div>
        <div class="content-2">
            <label>Label 2</label>
        </div>
        <div class="content-3">
            <label>Label 3</label>
        </div>
        <div class="content-4">
            <label>Label 4</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`#wrapper label:first-of-type` won't work as every `label` *is* the first of it's type within it's immediate parent. That's the key here, these sorts of selectors are always relative to the immediate parent.

So, you could do something like this:

`#wrapper div:first-child > label`

which would select any `label` elements which are an immediate child of a `div` which is the first child within it's parent

Comment: gotcha, so there's really no way to just select "the first label under the id of wrapper" ?

Comment: @noclist unfortunately, no, not with this sort of structure

Answer (score 2):

use nth-child

```css
#wrapper .content-1:nth-child(1) label{
background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="content-1">
            <label>Label 1</label>
        </div>
        <div class="content-2">
            <label>Label 2</label>
        </div>
        <div class="content-3">
            <label>Label 3</label>
        </div>
        <div class="content-4">
            <label>Label 4</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Xpath can do this easily, it would be something like this:
(//*[@id="wrapper"]//label)[1]

I have not found its equivalence in css yet.